# Why is my Nuget-lib not available from .NetStandard 2.0?

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I've created the Nuget "Uplink.NET" with the following Nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/01/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>uplink.NET</id>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <title>Connector to the storj-network</title>
    <authors>TopperDEL,Storj Labs Inc.</authors>
    <owners>TopperDEL,Storj Labs Inc.</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/TopperDEL/uplink.net</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://storj.io/press-kit/Storj-symbol.png</iconUrl>
    <description>This library provides access to the secure and decentralised Storj-network. It allows you to:
- create and delete buckets
- upload and download files

It is - like Storj itself - open source and developed on GitHub.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>(c) 2019 TopperDEL, Storj Labs Inc.</copyright>
    <tags>storj tardigrade storage decentralised secure bucket file xamarin android</tags>
    <repository type="git" url="https://github.com/TopperDEL/uplink.net.git" />

    <contentFiles>
      <files include="uplink.NET\bin\release\netstandard2.0\storj_uplink.dll" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="uplink.NET.targets" target="build\uplink.NET.targets" />
    <file src="uplink.NET.Droid\bin\Release\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid7.0\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET.Droid\bin\Release\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid7.1\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET.Droid\bin\Release\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid8.0\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET.Droid\bin\Release\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid8.1\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET.Droid\bin\Release\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" target="lib\MonoAndroid9.0\uplink.NET.Droid.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\uplink.NET.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0\uplink.NET.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\uplink.NET.dll" target="netstandard2.0\uplink.NET.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\uplink.NET.dll" target="lib\uap10.0.16299\uplink.NET.dll" />
    <file src="uplink.NET\storj_uplink.dll" target="storj_uplink.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I can add it to a NetStandard2.0 class library, but it gets Added as a PackageReference with the following entries:

```
<PackageReference Include="uplink.NET" Version="1.3.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

I now cannot access the objects within my lib. But the same Nuget is working with Xamarin.Android and UWP.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Remove `PrivateAssets` and `IncludeAssets`.

Comment: Yes, than it works. But why does it get added within the PackageReference from my Nuget/Nuspec? How can i stop it from being added automatically?

Comment: Well, it seems, this is not a bug but a feature. I accidentialy marked my nuget as developmentDependency as described here:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/DevelopmentDependency-support-for-PackageReference

Comment: Why do you need a .nuspec after all? With a multi-targeting SDK based project, it can generate a NuGet package automatically (which also avoids possible mistakes (like the miserable `contentFiles`).

Comment: Well - to be honest, I'm not an expert with this. But I have two Projects - one for Xamarin.Android and one for NetStandard and want to include both in my Nuget. Don't really know how to accomplish this. I any one is interested - the Project is open source and I appreciate PRs:
https://github.com/TopperDEL/uplink.net

Comment: You might wish others to send you a pull request, but what I talked about is the future trend, so yourself should study it. An example is https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/blob/11.3.0/SharpSnmpLib/SharpSnmpLib.csproj

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when a package is a development dependency, as [our NuGet docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#developmentdependency):

> With PackageReference (NuGet 4.8+), this flag also means that it will
>   exclude compile-time assets from compilation.

A [linked page](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/DevelopmentDependency-support-for-PackageReference) further explains:

> when package's developmentDependency is true, then set PrivateAssets
>   to All and ExcludeAssets to Compile on PackageReference item in
>   project, while:

- Installing package through VS NuGet UI or PMC
- Executing dotnet add
  package command Migrating existing project from packages.config to
  PackageReference

> Even though developmentDependency is true, don't do anything treat it as normal
>   PackageReference, while:

- Manually adding PackageReference item in project to add a package
- Upgrading existing VS instance from previous version to latest (which started supporting developmentDependency)

Comment: Thanks for wrapping it up!